# If I start using conda as my python package manager, should I uninstall previously installed packages from pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, conda

I've been using pip to install packages directly to my root directory, but I read recently that using a virtual environment like conda or virtualenv is better practice. If I start using conda now, should I uninstall my pip-installed packages? I use python for a variety of applications, including machine learning with both Keras and Pytorch.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the version that is installed using the conda environment is used by your code. However, in certain situations different version of the package installed using pip and conda can lead to conflicts.

A recommended way is to have a fresh install of the package using conda.

Comment: So I should uninstall my previously installed packages with pip THEN install fresh versions with conda?